# How to download .doc files using python in windows?

Tags: python, file, urllib

I am downloading a `.doc` file using python in windows. But the downloaded file is not in readable form.

```
import urllib
url = 'https://ums.lpu.in/assignments/Teacher/16920_CA3.doc'
data = urllib.urlopen(url)
with open('file1.doc','w') as f:    # wb also gives the same result
    f.write(data.read())
```

I am getting the file using this method but the file can't be read.
I tried many ways but none of them seems to be working.

Comment: Write it as a binary file (`'w' => 'wb'`)?

Comment: 'wb' also giving the same result

Comment: is it only text file ?

Comment: downloaded file is in .doc format but in unreadable form

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/1552748

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: @KunalSaini, writing it as binary file: `with open('file1.doc','wb') as f: ` worked for me

Comment: @downshift,  Did you try it in windows or linux ?

Comment: @KunalSaini I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: It works on linux and MAC but not on windows